# JSON parser disconnects debugger

Tags: json, debugging, windows-phone

I got the following code:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler()))
{
    client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30.0);
    var response = await client.PostAsync(requestString, content);
    json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var tk = JObject.Parse(json);
    if ((string)tk.GetValue("Ident") == "Message" && (int)tk.GetValue("Status") == 401)
        throw new AuthenticationException();
    return tk;
}
```

This is the base for calling a webservice for the app I'm working on. The thing is: Every time I step over this one line:

```
var response = await client.PostAsync(requestString, content);
```

I get an error message from Visual Studio saying "The network connection to {IP:PORT} has been lost. Debugging will be aborted."

And so I get disconnected (happens with Emulator and WP device). This is really annoying since I would like to debug the result, but no chance. As I just have noticed the connection breaks even if you continue. Once it hit's it, the connection get lost.

This is a very weird behavior. Any clues why this happens or what could trigger connection loss?

FYI I'm using Newtonsoft.Json for that.

Comment: try it with out the native message handler using (var client = new HttpClient())

Comment: That part was written by my collegue, but I guess it's required for the iOS and Android versions (or at least to speed those up). But I'll try. I could also imagine that it's a rare bug caused by OzCode or Visual Studio itself. So I'll repair VS and try disabling OzCode once. I'll get back once I've got the results.

Comment: Okay, a repair of VS obviously fixed that issue. Works fine now.